# Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token

Tags: java, eclipse

why is there syntax error on this line ( shown below )

```
package org.temp2.cod1;
import java.security.*;
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Code1 {

    byte[] plaintext = new byte[32];   // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< syntax error
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
      plaintext[i] = (byte) (i % 16);
    }

    byte[] key = new byte[16];
    SecureRandom r = new SecureRandom();
    r.nextBytes(key);

    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    SecretKeySpec k =  new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, k);
    byte[] encryptedData = c.doFinal(plaintext);
}
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You forgot the entry point method declaration. Try adding:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

before the line where you got the error.

Comment: eclipse suggested to add the 
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
is that ok ?

Comment: Yes - although you can omit the throws clause if you are not throwing any of those exceptions.

Answer (score 15):

your code should be inside a method. It appears to me that you have skipped the `public void method(..) {` line

Answer (score 0):

you add above code in a method main or other.
example: public static void Code1 () { }

Comment: Java convention is to start a method name with a lowercase letter.  Technically the code doesn't have to be in a method.  It could be in an initialization block for example.  The key thing is that the code hasn't started a proper code block and has mis-matched closing braces.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your code inside the method not to class, hence you are facing this issue. **Add your code inside a method, and it will resolve this issue.**